# what's the basic idea of creating 2d drawing of a 3d geometry in cads

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, cad

I want to know the basic idea of creating 2d views of a 3d geometry in cads like autocad, solidworks, and etc..
Here, I listed some basic ideas that I had reached now.
Which method are they used ? or any method I didn't listed ?

idea A:

1. first, to render every single face to a plane space.
2. then detect the boundaries of faces.
3. do something magic that can recognize the 2d curves from the boundary pixels .
4. do something magic again to recognize which segments of curves should be hiddened.
5. construct a final view from lines and curves generated from above steps.

idea B:

1. they create projection rules for every type of surface with boundary wires, like plane, cylinder, sphere, spline. And thoes rules can be used in all projection angles.
2. then, implement projection rules for every face, and finally they got a view of many curves.
3. to iterate all curves generated from step 2, and check the visibility of the curve.
4. construct a final view.

idea C:

1. first, tessellate every faces to many triangles.
2. then, found boundaries from triangles for every faces.
3. then, we got many polylines from step 2.
4. to iterate all polylines generated for every faces, and check the visibility of the polylines.
5. construct a final view.

[image]

Comment: the algorithm is projection of 3d along a specified plane. The math is simple

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection

Comment: hidden surface removal can be done with multiple ways, eg the painters algorithm and so on..

Comment: In some cases, the boundary of the projected face is not the same as the original 3d face. This can be hard to found out the boundaries. @NikosM.

Comment: One other approach (another formulation of same algorithm) is to rotate the object to align with the projected plane and simply draw on plane by reverse z-index (painters algorithm)

Comment: well, Yes I can do projection for every pixel and every point.But before that, How can I find out boundaries for every surface?@NikosM.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by finding the boundaries, you have a 3d model with specified vertices and faces

Comment: Please see the picture in my question. In order to create 3-projection views of a 3d model, I have to draw polyines for every face in that model. And that polylines is the boundary of a face in projection plane. In 3d cad software, a 3d model are alway in [BREP formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_representation). So I can extract face datas from every 3d model.

Comment: The contours are defined by the extreme vertices of the model when aligned with a specific plane. It is not that hard to extract the vertices which define the contour from all vertices (when already aligned with a projection plane). For example one can take the extreme vertices of each face which is on a boundary (that is there is no other face left or right or top or bottom depending on orientation).

Comment: this may help you as it contains several standard algorithms for 3d CAD http://www2.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~ehartmann/cdgen0104.pdf

Comment: Thanks for this information. I am reading the book now. @NikosM.

Comment: It's not that easy to find out all extreme vertices in some complicated condition(for example: complicate NURBS surface). But it's much easy to find out the extreme pixel on the projected plane. how about this approach:   
1. To find out the extreme vertices. I can first render the whole face on the projection plane.  
2. then find out all extreme pixel on that plane.  
3. And finally, I can find the corresponding extreme vertices.  
@NikosM.

Comment: CAD uses some primitives except lines and polygons, eg circles or curves all these are parametrised and can be projected as well to get projected curves (this is a more difficult issue and the model should include these), but in any case one can sample the curves and make a fine polyline if necessary

Comment: Yes, I think it's more difficult to find the contours of a projected face depends on primitive 3d surfaces or 3d curves directly. But we can find it depends on that tessellated faces.@NikosM.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it follows this way:

1. tessellate every face and edge to triangles and segments.
2. project all those triangles and segments to a plane.
3. then choose a suitable resolution to construct those projected triangles and segments to pixels with a height parameter.
4. found contours for every face and edge from those pixels.
5. set visible value for every pixel on that contour depends on the height parameter of a total pixel's view.
6. reconstruct line, circle, and polylines from pixels.

I tested this method for some models, and works well. below is one of them:

[image][image]